# Editing / grading a DEM raster? (Ex: detention pond and berm grading)

Tags: raster, dem, editing

I am looking for a way to adjust/edit the values in a DEM file, for example, to grade a detention pond and berm into existing LiDAR data. I have tried messing around with point shapefiles and the IDW tool, but I am wondering if there is a better way. I can provide any additional details as needed.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I have access to both Standard license ArcMap 10.7 and QGIS

Comment: Please always specify which of QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop you wish to ask about within a particular question so that it and its answers can be focussed on what you have tried and where you are stuck using that product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**QGIS** has a  simple and effective plugin named "[Serval](https://github.com/erpas/serval/wiki)" that I believe will help you out.  To install Serval, select *Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins > All* > and scroll down to Serval, and click the Install Plugin button.  A Serval toolbar section is thus created.

Using Serval is pretty straightforward.  It has 3 modes:

1. **Probing**: Use this mode to change the value of a *single* cell.  Click on a cell with the eyedropper cursor.  The cell's band value(s) will be displayed in the Serval toolbar spinbox(es).  Type in a new value(s) and - Voila! - the cell is updated.
2. **Drawing**: This mode is useful if you need to adjust *multiple* cells to the same value(s) (for example, you want to set all the cells in your detention pond to the same elevation).  Select the Serval **Drawing** button and then enter the new value(s) in the spinbox.  With the pencil cursor, click on those cells that are to receive the new value(s) and - Voila! - the cells are updated.
3. **Erasing**:  When this mode is selected, clicked cells are set to the raster's NoData value.

The Serval toolbar has *undo* and *redo* buttons.  However, if you exit the QGIS project, all changes are immediately applied to your raster.  Thus, it is a good idea to make a copy of your raster prior to using Serval.

There is a similar product for the **Arc** Desktop environment: [ARIS Grid and Raster Editor](https://www.aris.nl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=210:aris-grid-editor-for-arcmap&catid=64:arcgis-tools&Itemid=169&lang=en).  However, it costs $400, and that's on top of the price to purchase Arc Desktop.

I've used **Serval** and **ARIS**, and they both get the job done just fine.

Comment: The Serval tool sounds PERFECT. I was not aware of that. Thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: You're welcome!  Pretty amazing what collaborative, open-source software can do, eh?  By the way, if my answer helped, please feel free to click the green check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ESRI products and you have point data with the proposed final elevation values of your project you can create a TIN from those points.  Convert the TIN to a raster. Then replace that portion of the DEM with the raster version of your berm and pond.  There is a lot of help to get you there online and these steps use standard tools.
Some considerations are:

1. Ensure that your points use the same vertical datum as your LiDAR.
2. Build a polygon that represents the extent of the proposed construction to act as a barrier (hard polygon in TIN speak) to limit the TIN and resulting raster to the extent of the project.

Comment: Yeah I have though about using points, but not about the polygon for the barrier. Thank you for the help!